# Getting uEye camera to interface with Aruco / OpenCV

Tags: ros, opencv, ueye, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I have been trying to get the uEye camera to interface with the OpenCV library Aruco, following the instructions here: http://maztories.blogspot.com/2013/07/installing-aruco-augmented-reality.html.  I have made it to the last line, $ ./aruco_test_board live board.yml camera.yml 0.025 but evertime I run it I get Could not Open Video.  My uEye camera works with its own demos and ImageView, and shows up as ueye under ls /dev.  I have tried on two machines, running Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04, ROS Hydro and Indigo respectively.  Same error for both. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190482/getting-ueye-camera-to-interface-with-aruco-/-opencv/) by [hdejarnette](https://answers.ros.org/users/20036/hdejarnette/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-08-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

uEye cameras use a proprietary communication protocol (and driver daemon), which OpenCV does not support.

Consider using a ROS dirver for uEye (I recommend ueye_cam :D), and also see https://github.com/pal-robotics/aruco_ros

---

Originally posted by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) with karma: 193 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1